# How to @Inject object with generic type

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, vaadin7

I am working on project in our company and I have a problem with injecting object. Let's consider I have this entity provider :

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement 
public class EntityProviderBean<T> extends CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider<T> {

    public EntityProviderBean(Class<T> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
        setTransactionsHandledByProvider(false);
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = CoreApplication.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    protected void runInTransaction(Runnable operation) {
        super.runInTransaction(operation);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setEntityManager(em);
        setEntitiesDetached(false);
    }
}
```

and extended JPAContainer using the entity provider above

```
@UIScoped
public class IncidentContainer extends JPAContainer<Incident> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8360570718602579751L;

    @Inject
    EntityProviderBean<Incident> provider;

    public IncidentContainer() {
        super(Incident.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        setEntityProvider(provider);
    }

}
```

The problem is (and I understand it) that I am not able to @Inject object with class type definition, because inject method needs blank constructor. Is here some kind of solution how to make it works ? Now I am getting exception

```
org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:77)
```

Many thanks for the answers :) 
Ondrej

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the Bean needs a constructor with no arguments to be injectable or all the constructor parameters must be injected as well. You will not be able to fulfil these requirements.

Comment: Yes, I know about it :) I was curious if there is some kind of solution I don't know about. Otherwise I am going to make a list with these containers created explicitly.

Comment: In my project I just created a provider class for every entity I used for a JPAContainer.

Answer (score 0):

### Consrtutor Injection

When CDI container instantiate a bean class then it call the bean constructor of CDI bean.

CDI looks for the either default bean constructor or annotated with @Inject to get the the instance of bean.

- No parameter/default bean constructor will accepted by CDI container if CDI bean doesn't explicitly declare a constructor using @Inject.
- CDI bean constructor may have any number of parameters and container initialize/inject all those
   paramters which are injection point for the bean constructor.
- CDI bean class can only have single constructor annotated with @Inject. If CDI container finds multiple constructor annotated with @Inject then it throws error.

> There is one advantage of bean constructor injection it allows the
>   bean to be immutable.

The Problem in your case is

IncidentContainer bean class does not have any default constructor or  a constructor annotated with @Injection.

You can set as following

```
public class IncidentContainer extends JPAContainer<Incident> {

    // @Inject no need to do filed injection here
    private EntityProviderBean<Incident> provider;

    @Inject // add this one
    public IncidentContainer(EntityProviderBean<Incident> provider) {
        super(Incident.class);
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        setEntityProvider(provider);
    }
}
```

EntityProviderBean bean class does not have any default constructor or  a constructor annotated with @Injection.

You can set as following

```
public class EntityProviderBean<T> extends CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider<T> {

    public EntityProviderBean(Class<T> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
        setTransactionsHandledByProvider(false);
    }
    // add this cdi bean construtor
    @Inject
    public EntityProviderBean(Incident incident) {
        this((Class<T>) incident.getClass());
    }

    protected void runInTransaction(String operation) {
        super.runInTransaction(operation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for an idea, but I am still getting the same error, when I want to `@Inject IncidentContainer` somewhere.

Comment: Finally I get it to work. I am able to inject IncidentContainer, but when I want to save some entity into it, I got `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException`. That is because of `@TransactionManagement` annotation, which apparently does not work :( Do you have any ideas ?